# Loss increasing and accuracy decreasing

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I've implemented a shallow FC feedforward neural net with 2 input nodes, 1 hidden layer with 4 nodes (tanh activation) and 1 outputnode with sigmoid activation function and binary cross-entropy loss. I'm trying to classify sklearns make_moons() dataset, but when i train it the loss just keeps increasing and the accuracy decreasing. It's like its doing the opposite of learning. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import log


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))


def dsigmoid(x):
    y = sigmoid(x)
    return y*(1-y)


def tanh(x):
    return 2/(1+np.exp(-2*x)) - 1


def dtanh(x):
    return 1 - (tanh(x))**2


class ANN:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.w1 = np.random.normal(0, (2/6)**0.5, (4, 2))
        self.w2 = np.random.normal(0, (2/5)**0.5, (1, 4))
        self.b1 = np.zeros((4, 1))
        self.b2 = 0

    def feedforward(self, x):
        self.a = tanh(np.dot(self.w1, x.reshape(2, 1)) + self.b1)
        self.out = sigmoid(np.dot(self.w2, self.a) + self.b2)[0, 0]
        return int(round(self.out))

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        y = y[0, 0]
        z1 = np.dot(self.w1, x.T).reshape((4, 1))
        z2 = np.dot(self.w2, self.a)
        delta2 = np.multiply(self.dbi_crossent_loss(self.out, y), dsigmoid(z2))

        delta1 = np.multiply(np.dot(self.w2.T, delta2), dtanh(z1))
        self.dw2 = np.dot(delta2, self.a.T)
        self.dw1 = np.dot(delta1, x.reshape(1, 2))

        self.w2 -= self.n*self.dw2
        self.w1 -= self.n*self.dw1
        self.b1 -= self.n*delta1
        self.b2 -= self.n*delta2

        return self.bi_crossent_loss(self.out, y)

    def bi_crossent_loss(self, y_hat, y):
        return (-y*log(y_hat)) - (1-y)*log(1-y_hat)

    def dbi_crossent_loss(self, y_hat, y):
        return (-y/y_hat) + (1-y)/(1-y_hat)


X_train, Y_train = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=0.10)

network = ANN(0.01)

c = 0
l = 0
for j in range(5000):
    for i in range(np.shape(X_train)[0]):
        y = Y_train[i].reshape(1, 1)
        x = X_train[i].reshape(1, 2)
        y_hat = network.feedforward(x)
        c += 1 if int(round(y_hat)) == y else 0
        l += network.backprop(x, y)
    if j % 100 == 99:
        print('step: ', j*100, 'loss: ', l/50000, 'acc: ', c/500)
        c = 0
        l = 0


X_test, Y_test = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.10)

preds = np.zeros(Y_test.shape)
for i in range(np.shape(X_test)[0]):
    preds[i] = network.feedforward(X_test[i].reshape(1, 2))


# Draw decision boundry
x_min, x_max = X_test[:, 0].min() - 1, X_test[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X_test[:, 1].min() - 1, X_test[:, 1].max() + 1
h = (x_max-x_min)/400
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

grid_preds = np.zeros(xx.shape, dtype=int)
for i in range(xx.shape[0]):
    for j in range(xx.shape[1]):
        grid_preds[i, j] = network.feedforward(
            np.array([xx[i, j], yy[i, j]]))


plt.contourf(xx, yy, grid_preds, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral, alpha=0.8)
plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=preds)
plt.show()
```

In the end I also plot the test data and the decision boundry. I previously tried using only sigmoid functions instead of tanh, and I've also tried using MSE. When doing this the accuracy usually didn't seem to decrease rapidly, but the network only modelled a linear decision boundry. Can someone please take a look at my code and see if you see a mistake? I would very much appreciate it, as I am in a great hurry.

Comment: Try with network = ANN(0.001). It looks like its jumpy with error calculation.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't really degrade as much but it only models a linear function.